# Rails object attribute confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app I am performing the following steps:

User needs to login -> User creates an authorization -> A user is created

The app seems to be tripping up in the final step of the process.

I create an authorization successfully:

```
Authorization Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "authorizations".* FROM "authorizations" WHERE "authorizations"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "authorizations"."uid" = '2259711' LIMIT 1
Authorization attributes hash: {"id"=>1, "uid"=>"2259711", "provider"=>"facebook", "user_id"=>1, "created_at"=>Wed, 02 May 2012 06:06:13 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Wed, 02 May 2012 06:06:13 UTC +00:00}
```

But it then chokes on the user creation step:

```
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms

RuntimeError (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Line 21 of session controller is this: `session[:user_id] = @auth.user.id`

However this makes no sense because I have clearly initialized a user object with the proper id...

The code governing this step is as follows:

Session#create controller

```
def create
    # create the auth hash here
    auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']

    if session[:user_id]
      # Means our user is signed in. Add the authorization to the user
      User.find(session[:user_id]).add_provider(auth_hash)

      redirect_back_or User.find(session[:user_id])
#     render :text => "You can now login using #{auth_hash["provider"].capitalize} too!"
    else
      # Log him in or sign him up
      @auth = Authorization.find_or_create(auth_hash)

      # Create the session
      logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@auth.attributes.inspect}"
      session[:user_id] = @auth.user.id 
#       render :text => "Welcome #{auth.user.name}!"

      sign_in @auth.user
      redirect_back_or @auth.user
    end     
  end
```

Authorization find_or_create model method

```
def self.find_or_create(auth_hash)
        unless auth = find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"])
            user = User.create :name => auth_hash["info"]["name"], :email => auth_hash["info"]["email"]
            logger.debug "Within Authorization find_or_create: Person attributes hash: #{user.attributes.inspect}"
            auth = create :user => user, :provider => auth_hash["provider"], :uid => auth_hash["uid"]
        end
        auth
    end
```

UPDATE

When I try this: `logger.debug "User attributes hash: #{@auth.user.attributes.inspect}"`

In the sessions controller above I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Meaning that the user object is nil. Which shouldn't be the case since I call user.create inside the authorization `find_or_create` method...

Comment: Are any of @auth's properties set (provider or uid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `find_by_provider_and_uid` sets the user property, so if it succeeds you need to take that into account.

```
auth = find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"])

if auth.nil? # i don't know if nil is the right condition to check for, my active record fu is not up to date.
   # do your unless code
else
   #need to fetch and set user property
end

auth
```

Comment: You're right, I ran into an edge case where I had a dangling Authorization in the db (with a user object that was deleted). Should add in logic to handle that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the User is failing validations and is not actually being created. Change `User.create` to `User.create!`, and you'll see right away if it's failing validations, because it will throw an exception.